# MySQL - get results of subsequent queries when CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS is enabled

Tags: mysql

How can I receive results of subsequent queries when performing multiple queries if CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS option is enabled?

I need to capture errors for EACH of perfomed queries.

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php):

> To retrieve the resultset from the first query you can use [`mysqli_use_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php) or [`mysqli_store_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php). All subsequent query results can be processed using [`mysqli_more_results()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.more-results.php) and [`mysqli_next_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php).

That manual page continues with an example:

```
/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        /* print divider */
        if (mysqli_more_results($link)) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}
```